# Android Sqlite Attach Database

Tags: android, sqlite

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.abc2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "DB_BusData";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
  * Constructor
  * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
  * @param context
  */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
  * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist
}else{

//By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
//of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
this.getReadableDatabase();

try {

copyDataBase();

} catch (IOException e) {

throw new Error("Error copying database");

}
}

}

/**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
  * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
  * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
  * This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

if(myDataBase != null)
myDataBase.close();

super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

**Attach Database Code**

```
 public void ImportDatabase(){
            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            try { 
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
            } catch (IOException ioe) { 
            throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
            }  
            try {  
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
            }catch(SQLException sqle){  
            throw sqle;  
            }

            SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '/mnt/sdcard/database.sqlite' AS New_DB");  
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Tbl_Driver2 AS SELECT * FROM New_DB.Tbl_Driver;");

        }
```

this is the Log Cat Error

```
    12-22 22:47:11.664: E/AndroidRuntime(9007): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:   
no such table: New_DB.Tbl_Driver: CREATE TABLE Tbl_Driver2 AS SELECT * FROM New_DB.Tbl_Driver;
```

is this the correct way to attach Sqlite database? i want to create the new database table Tbl_Driver to the Apps database

Comment: Your code seems perfect. Could you please try ATTACH '/mnt/sdcard/database.sqlite' AS New_DB" instead of ATTACH DATABASE '/mnt/sdcard/database.sqlite' AS New_DB" . Also manually check your attached db for the table.